# "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion"

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, cs50, incompatibletypeerror

The following program is refusing to compile because of these errors:

```
vigenere.c:52:31: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to
  'string' (aka 'char *') from 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
  ...ciphertext[i] = ((((plaintext[i] - 65) + keyword[num % keylength]) % 26) + 65);
                   ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
vigenere.c:56:31: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to
  'string' (aka 'char *') from 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
  ...ciphertext[i] = ((((plaintext[i] - 97) + keyword[num % keylength]) % 26) + 97);
                   ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And here's the program, which is meant to implement a simple vigenere cipher:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid input; try again!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if(argv[1])
    {   
        for(int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
        {
            if(!isalpha(argv[1][i]))
            {
                printf("Invalid input; try again!\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // get plaintext from user
    string plaintext = GetString();
    string ciphertext[100];
    int num = 0;

    string keyword = argv[1];
    int keylength = strlen(keyword);

    // change key values from letters to shifts
    for(int i = 0, n = keylength; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(keyword[i]))
        {
            keyword[i] = keyword[i] - 65;
        }
        else if(islower(keyword[i]))
        {
            keyword[i] = keyword[i] - 97;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            if(isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {   
                ciphertext[i] = ((((plaintext[i] - 65) + keyword[num % keylength]) % 26) + 65);
            }
            else if(islower(plaintext[i]))
            {
                ciphertext[i] = ((((plaintext[i] - 97) + keyword[num % keylength]) % 26) + 97);
            }
            num++;
        }
        // non-alphabetic characters
        else 
        {
            ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
        }
        printf("%c", ciphertext[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I've no idea why the compiler throws the error, because I have an older version of the program, compiled a few months ago (the code is exactly the same on lines 52 and 56) which works just fine.

I'll really appreciate any and all help :)

Comment: What kind of type is `string` ? You declare an array of `string` for your `ciphertext` variable. I'd say check the types of your "older" version.

Comment: If that's a custom typedef, you just got bitten. ;-) `ciphertext` is an array of `char *`, I.e. array of *multiple* strings, and you're trying to assign single characters (`int`) to its elements (`char *`), which the compiler (rightfully) complains about. I think it's a very poor typedef, BTW...

Comment: "*I have an older version of the program, compiled a few months ago (the code is exactly the same on lines 52 and 56) which works just fine.*"

How did this older version of the code define `cyphertext`?

Comment: Note: do **not** use magic numbers. They can make your code near unreadable/unmaintainable (even more for homework). What's wrong with `'a'` and `'z'` instead of `65` and `97`? Even better: `toupper` or `tolower` (as you are already using `isupper`, etc.).

Comment: @Olaf: I love text-handling code that breaks as soon as Célia Šašić or László Erdős sit down at the keyboard and try to enter their names. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar oh cut me some slack, I started learning to code about a week ago ;)

Comment: @AgataS.: No problem at all -- but encryption is a curious choice for a beginner's subject. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Variable `ciphertext` is array of `char*`, I think it should be:

```
char ciphertext[1000]
```

Answer (score 2):

`ciphertext` is an array of type `string` (with `string` being a typedef'd `char *`).

So this

```
ciphertext[i]
```

evaluates to a `char *`.

```
((((plaintext[i] - 65) + keyword[num % keylength]) % 26) + 65)
```

evaluates to an `int`.

The code tries to assign an `int` to `char *`. This does not make sense (here).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the following statement leads to an `int` value:

```
((((plaintext[i] - 65) + keyword[num % keylength]) % 26)
```

On the receiving side it is a `string` or `char*`. Thus, the error.